# PostgreSQL csv import from a MySQL csv export?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, csv

Will it work?

MySQL export:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table;
```

PostgreSQL:

```
COPY table FROM 'C:/data.csv' WITH DELIMITER AS '\t' NULL AS '\\N' CSV
```

There is missing columns for some reason. So I believe there is problem in delimiter. Am I correct, what can I do? I can inspect row with cause error below. But which characters I must look for?

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "Column21"
CONTEXT:  COPY table, line 88219: ...
```

Comment: So at 88219 line contain sting with escaped quote: " ... \" ... " Seems like postgres fail to unquote this. Is there special option for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. As mentioned by @knitti postgres need to know escape character: ESCAPE '\'
2. OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' is bad format for csv. It's better to force quoting.

Full code:

mysql 5.5.15:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table;
```

postgres 9.0.3:

```
COPY table FROM 'C:/data.csv' WITH DELIMITER AS E'\t' NULL AS '\\N' ESCAPE E'\\' CSV
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for my friend!

Comment: I needed to escape the delimiter as E'\t' for the above to work

Answer (score 0):

Default quote character in PostgreSQL is double-quote, but [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-copy.html) says, you can use any single one-byte-character. Try adding

```
ESCAPE '\\'
```